# How Do Field Waves Stick Together?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, forces, atomic-physics

My question might be kinda weird, and I might not actually know what I am talking about. However, here goes my best shot at describing my confusion.

I've been thinking about the structure of an atom, and now have some confusion on why Protons and Neutrons "stick" together. I know that there is a strong force holding them together, however, from my understanding there are waves in specific fields that cause a particle to "exist" and vise versa. If that is the case, then how do these particles, neutron and protons, stick together if they are on different fields? How do different fields interact with each other to create these invisible forces?

Thank you,
Nate

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1489/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Particles such as the components of protons and neutrons, (quarks) and electrons are excitations of fields, (which are "permanent" excitations in the sense  that your hand is always the same when you look at it) and the atoms in your hand interact by utilising excitations of other fields.

So if you put your hand over a fire, it will heat up, (the energy from the fire will increase the energy of the molecules in your hand), then cool down when you remove it. Your hand will stay the same shape etc, but the electromagnetic radiation received  from the fire will disperse as the photons (excitations of the electromagnetic field) disperse into the environment.

Protons and neutrons and their quark components, stick together by constantly exchanging excitations of the fields underlying the charge carriers, such as photons, gluons and weak force bosons.

[image]

You need to read [QED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram) for an idea of how interactions are described.

Some interaction fields have excitations which are permanent, because they are massless, such as photons. Some have excitations which are temporary, such the weak force bosons, which have mass and short lifespans, inversely proportional to their mass.

Comment: And some excitations have mass, and would therefore normally be temporary, but are protected from decaying by a particular symmetry, which is how we get massive stable particles.